# Ubuntu terminal ¿How to move $ symbol? - noob question

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, server

First time using Linux and the console.

I'm doing a class activity and I have to do the following steps:

[Teacher's console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v10le.jpg)

As you can see, the symbol $ is behind apache2 and not in the begining of the sentence:

```
administrador@LinuxServer:/etc/apache2$ cat apache2.conf
```

I kwow probably is a noob question. But I can not copy the instruction.
Because in my console, always appears at the begining the ~$.

```
administrador@LinuxServer:~$/etc/apache2$ cat apache2.conf
```

[My console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LW91P.jpg). So it can't find the file.

¿How can I open correctly the file? I suppose is some keyboard shortcut...

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Try it on a new line without the other command in front. I don't know if it will make a difference, but it's worth trying.

Answer (score 2):

You need simply to change directory because you stay in the same directory which is `~`

```
admin20@dawserver:~$ cd /etc/apache2
```

Then read file :

```
admin20@dawserver:/etc/apache2$ cat apache2.conf
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) 

It worked, just another question. 

When I change it  ¿How can I go back? I mean to the default

Comment: Put command `cd ~`

Comment: Actually  `cd` command means change directory. It accepts a second parameter which is the directory. So to go back you need to specify `~` because it is your default directory.